# Generating Point Elliptic Curve

Tags: c, openssl, elliptic-curve

I'm studying Elliptic Cruve, and i'm learning OpenSSL for a quick implementation in C. Now i want to understand how can i generate a random number and multiply it with the Generator Point. Formally: An user generates a random number r_U \in [1,\dots, n - 1] and computes R_U= r_U \times G. ("I can't insert image because I have reputation less then 10").

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <openssl/bn.h>
#include <openssl/ec.h>
#include <openssl/obj_mac.h>

int main() {

    const EC_GROUP *curve;

    BIGNUM *r_U=BN_new();

    BIGNUM *n=BN_new();//Order Curve

    EC_KEY *key=NULL;

    const BIGNUM *c=BN_new(); //Private Key CA

    const EC_POINT *C; //Public Key CA

    EC_POINT *R_U; //R_U point

    BN_CTX *ctx;

    const EC_POINT *G; //Generator

    curve = EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp224r1);

    G=EC_GROUP_get0_generator(curve);

    EC_GROUP_get_order(curve,n,ctx);

    //Private Key and Public Key CA
    key = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp224r1);
    EC_KEY_generate_key(key);

    key_user = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp224r1);
    EC_KEY_generate_key(key_user);

    c=EC_KEY_get0_private_key(key);        

    printf("\nPrivate Key CA:%s",BN_bn2dec(c));


    return 0;
}
```

Now How can i generate a random number between 1 and n-1 and multiply it for G ? Can I use the function EC_POINT_mul ?
Thanks for support.

Comment: Also see [Elliptic Curve Cryptography](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Elliptic_Curve_Cryptography) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: Hi @jww, i already saw but i don't now how to use EC_POINT_mul to multiply an integer (scalar value) with a point. If I see the function: int EC_POINT_mul(const EC_GROUP *group, EC_POINT *r, const BIGNUM *n, const EC_POINT *q, const BIGNUM *m, BN_CTX *ctx), the "integer" is a BIGNUM. Can I use BN_rand() ? (i used this function but i have a segmentation fault error.